# Clarification on 1NF Violation - DBMS

Tags: database-design, normalization

I am designing a basic Course Database with 'Semester' as an entity. Here I have two attributes "Season" (Fall, Spring, Summer) and "Year" (2015, 2016, 2017).

If I replace these attributes to form a key called "Semester_Id" with values FALL16, SPRING16, FALL17 etc, am I violating 1st Normal form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivially, you would want the values to be 2016Fall, 2016Spring and 2016Summer so they would order in the correct grouping -- assuming year is academic year.

There is no need to replace the existing attributes. The combination of year and semester/season makes a perfectly good composite key just the way they are. Don't be afraid to use composite keys where they make sense.

Actually, you might consider pushing the semesters into their own lookup table and making the semester attribute a FK to it. Making Season a entity of its own would give you potentially useful extensions. The data in the lookup table could look like this:

```
ID   Name   Starts
 0   Fall   Last week of August
 1   Spring First week after the first Saturday of January
 2   Summer First week of May
```

There could be a lot of information concerning the season or semester you might want to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

If we view Semester_id as a composite attribute, then it violates 1NF by combining two domains into one column. However, if it's used only as an identifier without interpretation, it represents a single domain which is valid in a normalized relation.